# Why Qt can not capture touch event after re-plug USB touch device?

Tags: qt, hotplugging

Have a good day.

I have a problem about touch device's hot-plug.

I set the environment variable as below.
export QT_QPA_EVDEV_TOUCHSCREEN_PARAMETERS=/dev/input/ts_uinput:rotate=0

The "/dev/input/ts_uinput" is created by ts library's application "ts_uinput".

The touch function can work normally before I re-plug the USB touch device.
If I re-plug the USB touch device, the touch function doesn't work.

The "/dev/input/ts_uinput" still is created after I re-plug the USB touch device.

I also monitor the data in "/dev/input/ts_uinput" and it also has data report.

Why the Qt does not get the touch event after re-plug the USB touch device?

Comment: hey, I know its ben more than 2 years, but have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would boldly guess that this is because Qt (the Qt evdev platform plugin) opens `/dev/input/ts_uinput` when the app start. When you replug the touch device, the file is recreated but the file handle held by Qt has become invalid. Making it work again would require Qt to close and reopen the handle.

You could try getting more info by enabling debug logs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#debugging-input-devices

However, I do not know if this is a bug or a missing feature, you might want to contact the Qt [interest mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/interest) or [report a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io).